# How to connect to localhost python flask API using Python

Tags: python, api, flask

I have local python flask based api running. It is running on below base url:

```
http://localhost:80/

 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://localhost:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Here is the code for it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os

    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, 80)
```

I need to connect to the API for which the full URL is:

```
http://localhost:80/api/v1/face/recognize
```

I can connect to it using postman and getting good response. I have to connect to it using another python  project. For this I am using below code:

```
import http.client
import json

headers = {'appName': 'Tirunka', 'app_key': '6e0e36ff19de5623',
                           'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = {
    "imageUrl": "kf7ZrqtJ5Sucu02eL7kerZrOG7Or ........ and so on ..........Haypep1uir/AKRH9K662T92K5TRh/",
    "galleryName": 'test'
}

json_data = json.dumps(data)

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('http://localhost:80')
conn.request("POST", "/api/v1/face/recognize", json_data, headers)
```

At this line `conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('http://localhost:80/')`, I am getting below exception:

```
nonnumeric port: '80/'
```

I seem to have been using correct url. I am unable to understand the error. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) (emphasis is mine) :

> An HTTPConnection instance represents one transaction with an HTTP server. It should be instantiated passing it a host and optional port number. If no port number is passed, **the port is extracted from the host string if it has the form host:port** else the default HTTP port (80) is used.

Your string does not respect the format `host:port`. Remove the trailing slash, or specify the port with the keyword argument :

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('http://localhost:80/') # does not work (InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '80/')
```

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('http://localhost:80') # works
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('http://localhost',port=80) # works
```

Comment: Okay with `('http://localhost',port=80)`. It works and didnt showed any error. But at line `conn.request("POST", "/api/v1/face/recognize", json_data, headers)`. It showed error `[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`. Can you tell, why

Comment: You should use the full url, and not the just the route. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request). You could consider using the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library, which is considerably simpler to use as it offers a high level interface.